# SonarQube not displaying classes under coverage

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have been working on setting up code coverage metric on SonarQube for a Java project using jacoco plugin.

The project builds successfully (using ant), jacocoreport.xml and jacocoreport.csv files get generated with the right information on covered/missed counter values for the covered/uncovered classes and methods. However, the dashboard on SonarQube reports "0.0%" as the metric value even when there is a single class file which has a covered method, and it provides absolutely NO information on "what classes have what coverage". In fact, upon clicking "0.0%" coverage link, I do not see (under "List" or "Tree") the particular folder which contains the classes I have written jUnit Tests for.

I checked with another developer from a different project who has worked on this before. She tells me that her project has around 2000 Unit Test methods and her jacoco.exec file size is 6MB. My project, on the other hand, has 1 to 2 Unit Test method(s) and the file-size is 6KB. Not sure if the jacoco.exec is generated properly.

How do I make sure the dashboard gives information on the covered/uncovered classes? Do you think it's not reporting because the the project has just one covered class file. I don't think this should be a problem. But I am not sure what's wrong.

NOTE: While running the Sonar Scanner locally, I noticed warnings that said some of the class files couldn't be accessed through the ClassLoader. This issue didn't get resolved even after me adding Sonar.Libraries and Sonar.Binaries properties (please ignore uppercase in this text).

Comment: What version of SonarQube do you use and what relevant plugins (versions) are installed?

Comment: SonarQube version - 5.6.3,
Sonar Scanner version 2.8 is on the server. [3.2 is what I use locally],
sonar-java-plugin-3.13.1.jar

Comment: Please add the `sonar.properties` file content.